# How to find single quotes and replace them by two single quotes in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, quote

I need to find single quotes in the text and replace them by two single quotes like this for instance :

l'arbre

=>

l''arbre

There are already a lot of places with two single quotes in the text, so I can't just use the find/replace function because it will pick up all those two single quotes together and they should stay so, without being modified.

Does anyone know how to do this ? I think I have to use regular expression but none that I've tried so far really work.

Thanks !

Comment: slightly off topic i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `ctrl` + `h` and in normal mode (no regex) :

1) replace `'` by `''`

2) replace `''''` by `''`

Comment: I forgot to precise that there are already a lot of places with two single quotes in the text, so I can't just use the find/replace function because it will pick up all those two single quotes together and they should stay so, without being modified.

That's why I thought regex is the only option...

Answer (score 1):

Press `ctrl` + `F`, go to the second tab(or `ctrl` + `h`).

- Put `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` on the first input.
- Put `\1"\2` on the second input.
- On search type, select regular expression.
- Press replace all.

Matches: `text'text`, `09text09'09text09`, `text'09text09`, `09text09'text`

Doesn't match: `text'`, `'text`, `'`

Comment: I forgot to precise that there are already a lot of places with two single quotes in the text, so I can't just use the find/replace function because it will pick up all those two single quotes together and they should stay so, without being modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
find what: '
replace with: ''
```

works for me. no regex required

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `([^'])(['])([^'])`

Replace with: `\1''\3`

This replaces only single quotes with double and leaves the double that are already there unchanged

Comment: This doesn't work when the single quote is the first (or last) character of the string. Foexample, try it with `'blah blah'` You'd better use lookaround.